# Choppy animations in desktop using fglrx driver in openSUSE 11.4

Tags: kde, opensuse, radeon, fglrx

I downloaded and installed the ATI driver, but my desktop effects were not working. Moving windows creates choppy animations.

I changed the rendering backend in kwin from openGL to xrender and the desktop effects worked, but my 3Dchess din't work because in my hardware profile the driver for my video card still says Radeon via modprobe instead of fglrx.

I aslo tried installing from level 3 and also ran `aticonfig --initial`.

`xorg.conf`:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier     "aticonfig Layout"
        Screen      0  "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 0 0
EndSection

Section "Module"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
        Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
        Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
        Option      "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
        Driver      "fglrx"
        BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
        Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
        Monitor    "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
        DefaultDepth     24
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     24
        EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Xorg log:

```
[   199.425]
X.Org X Server 1.9.3
Release Date: 2010-12-13
[   198.439] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   198.439] Build Operating System: openSUSE SUSE LINUX
[   198.439] Current Operating System: Linux linux-8ff2 2.6.37.1-1.2-desktop #1 SMP PREEMPT 2011-02-21 10:34:10 +0100 x86_64
[   198.439] Kernel command line: root=/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD5000BEVT-75ZAT0_WD-WXV0A49E6829-part9 resume=/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD5000BEVT-75ZAT0_WD-WXV0A49E6829-part7 splash=silent quiet vga=0x317
[   198.439] Build Date: 22 February 2011  10:08:09PM
[   198.439]
[   198.439] Current version of pixman: 0.20.0
[   198.439]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   198.439] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   198.439] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Jun 30 01:44:40 2011
[   198.440] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[   198.440] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   198.440] (==) ServerLayout "aticonfig Layout"
[   198.440] (**) |-->Screen "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" (0)
[   198.440] (**) |   |-->Monitor "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
[   198.440] (**) |   |-->Device "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
[   198.440] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   198.440] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   198.440] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/TTF/" does not exist.
[   198.440]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   198.440] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/OTF/" does not exist.
[   198.440]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   198.440] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/misc/sgi" does not exist.
[   198.441]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   198.441] (==) FontPath set to:
        /usr/share/fonts/misc:unscaled,
        /usr/share/fonts/Type1/,
        /usr/share/fonts/100dpi:unscaled,
        /usr/share/fonts/75dpi:unscaled,
        /usr/share/fonts/URW/,
        /usr/share/fonts/cyrillic:unscaled,
        /usr/share/fonts/truetype/
[   198.441] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib64/xorg/modules/updates,/usr/lib64/xorg/modules"
[   198.441] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
        If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[   198.441] (II) Loader magic: 0x7dc040
```

LSPCI:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset PCI Express Graphics Port (rev 07)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
00:1a.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03)
00:1a.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 4 (rev 03)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 6 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation ICH9M/M-E SATA AHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc M92 [Mobility Radeon HD 4500 Series]
01:00.1 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc RV710/730
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5784M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 10)
09:01.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller (rev 05)
09:01.1 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter (rev 22)
09:01.2 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C592 Memory Stick Bus Host Adapter (rev 12)
09:01.3 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd xD-Picture Card Controller (rev 12)
```

Comment: Post your /etc/X11/xorg.conf, please. Also /var/log/Xorg.0.log or whatever your most recent X log file is called.

Comment: I tried editing your question to help a little but cannot even figure out how the bit about modprobe and the hardware profiler is supposed to fit together. Please actually describe what shows up where and what steps you have taken.

Comment: ok sorry about the posting! Let me give u the xorg.conf and log files.

http://pastebin.com/zu7j7XSr

http://pastebin.com/CCDF3UP8

Comment: @Aadi: Tip: if you want username to be notified of your comment, prefix it with @username. In general, paste into your question rather than link to third party paste sites, unless the paste is excessively long (not the case here). Did you really paste all of the log? I only see 41 lines? How did you get the BusID for the device in xorg.conf? Post `lspci`.

Comment: Where did you install fglrx from? I followed [this guide](http://lizards.opensuse.org/2011/02/19/atiamd-fglrx-catalyst-for-opensuse/) and it worked like a charm. That repository also gets updates.

Comment: @Aadi: Also post output of `lspci`. Also list your card, and the version of fglrx you are using. Your X log as posted looks truncated.

Comment: I've lspci to the question. Thanks. @VPeric i did the exact things shown in the link you gave but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey guys I had done a very small mistake i din install kernel source, realise ATI needs kernel source for build. Now i installed it and all works fine. Thanks for the help.